# How to create multiple versions of a model in GCP ML Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

GCP has a multiple version capability for models.  You can even specify a version as a default.   However, how do you actually upload multiple models?

For instance, this command will create a model if the model name does not exist.

```
%%bash
MODEL_LOCATION=$(gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}/${MODEL_NAME}/${TRAINING_DIR}/export/exporter | tail -1)

DESCRIPTION="Has multiple bang count entries. 1200 training samples"

gcloud ml-engine versions create ${MODEL_VERSION}_${MODEL_SUBVERSION} \
--model ${MODEL_NAME} \
--origin ${MODEL_LOCATION} \
--runtime-version $TFVERSION \
--description="${DESCRIPTION}" \
--labels='some_key'="${SOME_VALUE}",another_key="another_value"
```

However, each time I bump the model version, I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) ALREADY_EXISTS: Field: version.name Error: A version with the same name already exists.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: A version with the same name already exists.
    field: version.name
```

Comment: New command is `gcloud ai-platform versions create` that aside what do you see in UI? Can you also clarify the values of MODEL_VERSION and MODEL_SUBVERSION, error seems to be very straightforward, you are using same name for an existing model version.  Correct way of the commands is to use ```gcloud ai-platform models create $MODEL_NAME \
 --regions $REGION``` to create your model and then multiple ```gcloud beta ai-platform versions create ...``` for different versions of it.